# How to sum the values of specific keys while iterating over a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sum

> Create a solution that accepts an integer input identifying how many
> shares of stock are to be purchased from the Old Town Stock Exchange,
> followed by an equivalent number of string inputs representing the
> stock selections. The following dictionary stock lists available stock
> selections as the key with the cost per selection as the value.
>
> ```
> stocks = {'TSLA': 912.86 , 'BBBY': 24.84, 'AAPL': 174.26, 'SOFI': 6.92, 'KIRK': 8.72, 'AURA': 22.12, 'AMZN': 141.28, 'EMBK': 12.29, 'LVLU': 2.33}
>
> Output the total cost of the purchased shares of stock to two decimal places.
>
> The solution output should be in the format
>
> Total price: $cost_of_stocks
> Sample Input/Output:
> If the input is
>
> 3
> SOFI
> AMZN
> LVLU
> then the expected output is
>
> Total price: $150.53"
> ```

Hi everyone, working on some practice assignments in zybooks and this one is consistently stumping me.

```
stocks = {'TSLA': 912.86, 'BBBY': 24.84, 'AAPL': 174.26, 'SOFI': 6.92,
          'KIRK': 8.72, 'AURA': 22.12, 'AMZN': 141.28, 'EMBK': 12.29, 'LVLU': 2.33}
selections = int(input())
i = 0
for i in range(selections):
    choices = (input())
    if choices in stocks:
        print((stocks[choices]))
```

This is currently what I have tested and it outputs the correct values of whatever Key I enter as well as whatever number of keys I want to enter

```
IE
input
3
TSLA
BBBY
AMZN

output
912.86
24.84
141.28
```

But I cannot use `sum()` as it gives me a type error. How would I go about getting a specific number of inputs from the user, assigning that to a loop so it only iterates as many times as the user specified, and then outputting the SUM of the values associated with the keys the user inputs?

Thank you :)

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: I don't see where you would be able to easily drop sum() into this. You need to create a variable outside of the loop like `total = 0`, then instead of printing the price, add it to the total with `total += stocks[choices]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable like `res` to keep adding up your current result.

It's better to include the `input()` for selected stocks' names outside the loop and stores them in an appropriate data structure, like an array, in this case.

Also, I assume that the `input()` is guaranteed valid, which is true for the website you mentioned.

```
stocks = {'TSLA': 912.86, 'BBBY': 24.84, 'AAPL': 174.26, 'SOFI': 6.92, 'KIRK': 8.72, 'AURA': 22.12, 'AMZN': 141.28,
          'EMBK': 12.29, 'LVLU': 2.33}

number_of_selection = int(input())
stock_selection = [input() for _ in range(number_of_selection)]

res = 0
for stock in stock_selection:
    res += stocks[stock]

print(f'Total price: ${res}')
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh ok, this helped a ton. So in that case, was my placing of "choices = input()" inside the for loop incorrect? Was that input even doing anything?

Comment: I think you need to create a variable for adding up the stock prices, like `res` in the code above. In your case, the result is printed immediately after each iteration, not the total sum of all stocks purchased. It's better to separate `input()` and the loop.

Comment: *It's better to include the input() for selected stocks' names outside the loop and stores them in an appropriate data structure, like an array, in this case.* -- OP doesn't need all of the stocks at once. This is bad advice. Processing them individually means you don't actually need to load them all into memory at once.

Comment: @Mpeon82 reading the choice inside the loop was the better option.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In this problem is can save some memory but putting the input() inside the loop; time complexity won’t be affected. I think that for problems in this particular website, for some advanced problem, data manipulation is needed, so it is instinct to store them in a set or array. That’s another story. In this particular, as it is simple, your judgment are correct.